# Align a image and overlay text in center of page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a image with some text in the middle of the page. The image gets to the center correctly , but the overlay text is off center. Below is the code. The text should be in the top left of the image.

```
<div class="w3-content">
<div class="w3-row-padding" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="w3-display-container">
        <img src="w3images/house5.jpg" alt="House" style="width:50%;"  class="animated fadeInRight slower">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding animated fadeInRight slower">Summer House</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the text on top of the image, I think you should either use the image as a background image, or use absolute position.

```
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.image-wrap .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jymqj51r/

Answer (score 1):

Did some changes and got this to work.. THanks all

```
<div class="w3-container animated fadeInRight slower w3-white "  style="float: right;">
<div class="w3-display-container" >
<div><img src="w3images/house2.jpg" ></div>
<div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">My Summer House</div>
</div>
</div>
```